# If $N$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$ then $C_G(N)$ is also normal.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $N$ be an abelian normal subgroup of $G$. I want to show that $C_G(N)$, the centralizer of $N$ in $G$ is also normal in $G$.

Since $N$ is abelian, it is clear that $N\leq C_G(N)$. But I don't know how to show that $C_G(N)$ is normal in $G$.

Any hint?

Comment: Well you have to show that $g^{-1}h g \in C_G(N)$ for all $g \in H$ and $h \in C_G(N)$, or in other words $g^{-1}hgn = ng^{-1}hg$ for all $g \in G$, $h \in C_G(N)$, $n \in N$. Why don't you at least make some attempt at proving this, rather than just saying that you don't know how to do it? (BTW, the assumption that $N$ is abelian is not needed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $c\in C_G(N)$ and take $g\in G$. For any $n\in N$,
\begin{align}
gcg^{-1}n&=gc(g^{-1}ng)g^{-1}\\
&=g(g^{-1}ng)cg^{-1}\\
&=ngcg^{-1}
\end{align}
and thus $gcg^{-1}\in C_G(N)$.

Comment: *sighs* why the downvote